# Is there anyway to scan a qrcode file in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, barcode, zxing

Is there anyway to scan a qrcode file in external storage in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan barcodes without end-to-end handling, you can use Google's ML-Kit for the same... it's easy to use

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning